# WordPress (4.3.1) dropdown tabs not working in Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When in WordPress (4.3.1) on my live site the dropdown  tabs at the top (Screen Option, Help, etc.) in the dashboard are not working. I did a bit of research and removed all plugins and custom jquery with the same result.
All works fine on my local server.
Does anyone have any ideas or where to look to make them work?
Thanks.

Thanks to the comments below here is a shot of the console errors:

[image]

Comment: Does the console of your debugging tool shows errors?

Comment: Yes! Great idea,I should have checked for that. The main error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. I took a screen shot if that would help.

Comment: have you made any edits to backend codes ? seems like if the code is overrided by some other code. paste the screenshot link let's check

Comment: I don't think I have made any edits to backend code. Also it does work on my local host and the two are pretty much in sync.

Comment: Do you have access to your web server `php.ini`? If yes, check if the `magic_quotes` options is enabled and try disabling it. You should also [change your wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging) to allow some debugging functionalities.

Comment: I might have access to php.ini (It's shared hosting). Will that fix the errors above?